# How to navigate to a ViewModel that extends an abstract class?

Tags: mvvm, mvvmcross

I am trying to share viewmodels as much as possible using MVVMCross's suggested assembly architecture:

```
MyApp.App
└ ViewModels
  ├ GlobalViewModel1
  └ GlobalViewModel2 (abstract)

MyApp.Droid
├ Views
│ ├ View1
│ └ View2
└ ViewModels
  └ ChildOfGlobalViewModel2

MyApp.Store
├ Views
│ ├ View1
│ └ View2
└ ViewModels
  └ ChildOfGlobalViewModel2
```

I can correctly navigate to `View1` and its associated viewmodel `GlobalViewModel1`, but it gets more complicated when I want to navigate to `View2` because its viewmodel varies slightly from one platform to another.

I assumed that if I registered `Mvx.RegisterType<GlobalViewModel2, ChildOfGlobalViewModel2>()` on each platform, then when `GlobalViewModel1` would be able to navigate by using `this.ShowViewModel<GlobalViewModel2>()`. Apparently I was wrong, since I get an exception when the app tries to instantiate the abstract class.

I do view look up initialization manually by overriding `InitializeViewLookup`, so I tried associating the view to the parent and the child classes, but none of those configurations was successful.

I already solved the problem once by injecting the desired behaviour because it was pertinent to encapsulate it in a class, but in some cases this approach would only force me to create a number of classes that will make the code less readable and the apps harder to maintain in the future.

Is there some configuration I am missing or should I change my approach? If so, what is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setup in MvvmCross is navigation by viewmodel - this doesn't include navigation by inheritance.

You could override parts of mvx in order to support your abstract scenario if you really wanted to. However, I think this would be more effort than it is worth.

Instead, I would suggest either:

- registering a service `IG2Service` which has a single property called `G2Type`.  Each platform could then `set` the VM Type for your Global2 and your navigation could then call the `get` before performing the navigation. Note: using this technique, you won't be able to use the `ShowViewModel<T>` overrides to navigate this way, but the non-generic overrides should work fine.
- or (if possible) refactoring your code so that your g2 view models use platform specific code via dependency injection rather than via inheritance.

Comment: We had come to the same conclusion. I'm curious as to what interfaces should be implemented to navigate to an abstract class or event an interface, though. Because in some cases injection will definitely require some potentially unreadable code :/

Comment: The easiest implementation would be to replace IMvxViewDispatcher or Presenter with an object that uses reflection across all loaded assemblies in order to find a concrete implementation of your abstract class - it could then substitute the abstract-containing MvxViewModelRequest with a new concrete-containing one.