# mvvm - navigate to same View from multiple ViewModels in mvvmcross

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, mvvmcross

I'm currently using `fragments` with **1-View-to-1-ViewModel** mapping. However, I have a special case where a `View` **A** (as `fragment`) is bound to `ViewModel` **A**, with a `ViewModel` **B** that extends `ViewModel` **A**. Instead of having a `View` **B** for `ViewModel` **B**, is it possible to use **View** `A` for **ViewModel** `B`?

As I'm doing navigation through `ViewModels`, both `ViewModel` **B** or `ViewModel` **A** should lead to `View` **A**.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Since I'm still new to this I have only done some research. I don't if it would make sense to use **1-View-to-2-ViewModels** mapping? If so, I can see that `MvxFragment` only supports one generic `ViewModel` parameter, therefore I don't know if this can be only achieved by own implementation?

**UPDATE:**
I found some answers and I'm about to test them out:

[Register a single View as the View for Multiple ViewModels - MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042460/register-a-single-view-as-the-view-for-multiple-viewmodels-mvvmcross)

[How can i use one view for different view models in mvvmcross?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075729/how-can-i-use-one-view-for-different-view-models-in-mvvmcross)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the folowing approach by making another `View`**A**  that can be extended by other `Views`:

```
    class ViewA<TViewModel> : BaseView<TViewModel> where TViewModel : ViewModelA
    {
      // view init and logic
    }
    
    class ViewA : ViewA<ViewModelA> { }
    
    class ViewB : ViewA<ViewModelB> { }
```